# Trouble Getting my Method to Loop

Tags: c#, csv, methods, logic

I have made small CSV conversion program and one of my methods called `OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput()` is being called but is not looping to print out each field in my record file. **I have the while loop empty at the moment because I do not know how to build it.**

Everything else in the code is perfectly fine but it seems that I do not know how to get this method to loop. I am using global static variables but none seem to be able to be used to help me in this situation.

The method is supposed to print out each of the fields but skip the commas that are within the fields so that the fields do not get "split up".

Can anyone see what I am missing? I am new but desire to learn as much as I can!

---

Here is my code

---

```
class Program
{
    // File object variables
    static TextFieldParser input = new TextFieldParser("PPVendingPricing.csv");
    static StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("convertedInventoryItemListTacMed.csv");

    // Input and output buffer variables
    static string[] inputBuffer;
    static string[] outputBuffer = new string[40];


    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures();
        OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput();

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        input.Close();
        output.Close();
        Console.Read();
    }

     /*
     * This method reads the input file and fill data structures
     * that are used to organize the data before moving selected
     * fields to the output buffer.
     */ 
    public static void ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures()
    {
        input.SetDelimiters(",");

        input.ReadFields(); // Skip the header record.

        while (!input.EndOfData)
        {
            inputBuffer = input.ReadFields(); // Read a CSV record in to the inputBuffer. 
        }
    }

    /*
    * This method loads default values into the output
    * buffer (string array). Some of these values will be 
    * replaced before the output buffer is written to the file.
    */
    public static void SetOutputBufferDefaultValues()
    {
        // Initialize all fields to empty.
        for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            outputBuffer[i] = "";
        }

        // Update selected fields with default values.
        outputBuffer[7] = "Solutions Inc";
        outputBuffer[10] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[11] = "FIFO";
        outputBuffer[15] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[17] = "Main";
        outputBuffer[19] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[21] = "Solutions Inc";
        outputBuffer[25] = "Main";
        outputBuffer[28] = "Periods of Supply";
        outputBuffer[32] = "1";
        outputBuffer[35] = "By Overall Item Qty";
        outputBuffer[36] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[37] = "TRUE";
    }

    /*
    * This method maps selected values from the input buffer
    * to the appropriate position in the output buffer.
    */
    public static void MapInputFieldsToOutputFields()
    {
        outputBuffer[0] = inputBuffer[26];
        outputBuffer[1] = inputBuffer[38];
        outputBuffer[2] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[3] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[4] = inputBuffer[40];
        outputBuffer[5] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[6] = inputBuffer[27];
        outputBuffer[12] = inputBuffer[13];
        outputBuffer[13] = inputBuffer[39];
        outputBuffer[14] = inputBuffer[38] + " " +inputBuffer[40];
        //skipping outputBuffer[16] position 17 on spreadsheet
        outputBuffer[20] = inputBuffer[36];
        outputBuffer[22] = inputBuffer[37];
        outputBuffer[23] = inputBuffer[39];
        outputBuffer[24] = inputBuffer[40];
        outputBuffer[29] = inputBuffer[27];
        outputBuffer[33] = inputBuffer[18];
        outputBuffer[34] = inputBuffer[19];
        outputBuffer[38] = inputBuffer[39];
    }

    /*
     * This method uses the fields (array elements) in the output
     * buffer to assemble a CSV record (string variable). The
     * CSV record is then written to the output file.
     */
    public static void BuildRecordAndWriteOutput()
    {
        string record = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            if (outputBuffer[i].Contains(","))
            {
                string x = "\"" + outputBuffer[i] + "\"";
                record += x;
            }
            else
            {
                record += outputBuffer[i];
            }
            if (i < outputBuffer.Length - 1)
            {
                record += ",";
            }
        }

        output.WriteLine(record);
    }

    /*
     * This method retrieves information that has been organized and
     * placed into data structures. The information is then formatted,
     * placed into, and written to a CSV file.
     */
    public static void OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput()
    {
        while ()
        {
            SetOutputBufferDefaultValues(); // Put default values in the output buffer
            MapInputFieldsToOutputFields(); // Move fields from the input buffer to the output buffer.
            BuildRecordAndWriteOutput(); // Build record from output buffer and write it.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to see the issue with all this code. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help in answering the question, or in the process of creating one you would find your error.

Comment: Not for nothing but there are numerous CSV parser libs around like FileHelpers and CSVHelper which already do this and much, much more

Comment: @Plutonix I understand. I simply am doing this to learn the logic and to practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: after reading stuartd's comment, it looks like you want your `input.EndOfData` conditional in the `OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput()` loop.  So your program will look something like:

```
class Program
{
// File object variables
static TextFieldParser input = new TextFieldParser("PPVendingPricing.csv");
static StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("convertedInventoryItemListTacMed.csv");

// Input and output buffer variables
static string[] inputBuffer;
static string[] outputBuffer = new string[40];


static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput();

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    input.Close();
    output.Close();
    Console.Read();
}

 /*
 * This method reads the input file and fill data structures
 * that are used to organize the data before moving selected
 * fields to the output buffer.
 */ 
public static void ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures()
{
    input.SetDelimiters(",");

    inputBuffer = input.ReadFields(); // Read a CSV record in to the inputBuffer. 
}

/*
* This method loads default values into the output
* buffer (string array). Some of these values will be 
* replaced before the output buffer is written to the file.
*/
public static void SetOutputBufferDefaultValues()
{
    // Initialize all fields to empty.
    for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
    {
        outputBuffer[i] = "";
    }

    // Update selected fields with default values.
    outputBuffer[7] = "Solutions Inc";
    outputBuffer[10] = "TRUE";
    outputBuffer[11] = "FIFO";
    outputBuffer[15] = "TRUE";
    outputBuffer[17] = "Main";
    outputBuffer[19] = "TRUE";
    outputBuffer[21] = "Solutions Inc";
    outputBuffer[25] = "Main";
    outputBuffer[28] = "Periods of Supply";
    outputBuffer[32] = "1";
    outputBuffer[35] = "By Overall Item Qty";
    outputBuffer[36] = "TRUE";
    outputBuffer[37] = "TRUE";
}

/*
* This method maps selected values from the input buffer
* to the appropriate position in the output buffer.
*/
public static void MapInputFieldsToOutputFields()
{
    outputBuffer[0] = inputBuffer[26];
    outputBuffer[1] = inputBuffer[38];
    outputBuffer[2] = inputBuffer[3];
    outputBuffer[3] = inputBuffer[3];
    outputBuffer[4] = inputBuffer[40];
    outputBuffer[5] = inputBuffer[3];
    outputBuffer[6] = inputBuffer[27];
    outputBuffer[12] = inputBuffer[13];
    outputBuffer[13] = inputBuffer[39];
    outputBuffer[14] = inputBuffer[38] + " " +inputBuffer[40];
    //skipping outputBuffer[16] position 17 on spreadsheet
    outputBuffer[20] = inputBuffer[36];
    outputBuffer[22] = inputBuffer[37];
    outputBuffer[23] = inputBuffer[39];
    outputBuffer[24] = inputBuffer[40];
    outputBuffer[29] = inputBuffer[27];
    outputBuffer[33] = inputBuffer[18];
    outputBuffer[34] = inputBuffer[19];
    outputBuffer[38] = inputBuffer[39];
}

/*
 * This method uses the fields (array elements) in the output
 * buffer to assemble a CSV record (string variable). The
 * CSV record is then written to the output file.
 */
public static void BuildRecordAndWriteOutput()
{
    string record = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
    {
        if (outputBuffer[i].Contains(","))
        {
            string x = "\"" + outputBuffer[i] + "\"";
            record += x;
        }
        else
        {
            record += outputBuffer[i];
        }
        if (i < outputBuffer.Length - 1)
        {
            record += ",";
        }
    }

    output.WriteLine(record);
}

/*
 * This method retrieves information that has been organized and
 * placed into data structures. The information is then formatted,
 * placed into, and written to a CSV file.
 */
public static void OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput()
{
    input.ReadFields(); // Skip the header record.
    while (!input.EndOfData)
    {
        ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures();
        SetOutputBufferDefaultValues(); // Put default values in the output buffer
        MapInputFieldsToOutputFields(); // Move fields from the input buffer to the output buffer.
        BuildRecordAndWriteOutput(); // Build record from output buffer and write it.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I think the problem is in `while (!input.EndOfData)
        {
            inputBuffer = input.ReadFields(); // Read a CSV record in to the inputBuffer. 
        }`

Comment: It seems to only pick up the first record :/ maybe it's the layout of my methods? Maybe I should place the variables or call the methods else where? Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Yes the code in my example will only loop once, since I'm just showing the simplest case.  If you add the end condition of the loop where `testConditional` is, then it should work for you.

Comment: Also, look into stuartd's comment, since it seems like you are reassigning the inputBuffer variable with each iteration of the loop, which may not be what you want.

Comment: that is what I am wanting because I am using as a place holder :) How do I make your suggestion loop through more then just once? Thank you both

Comment: Just updated my answer with stuartd's comment.  I reorganized the code so that the main loop happens in `OrganizeDataAndCreateOutput()`.